# Web Audio API Play Notes after each other

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm relatively new to Javascript and I was trying to play notes using the Web Audio API. The notes do play but not as I would like them. I'm trying to get notes to play **after** each other. Each node in my code has an Array of frequencies. I then use a for loop to go through this array and play the frequencies using the function `playNote`. I tried using a timeOut to add a delay the playNote calls in the for loop but that didn't seem to work.

```
class Node {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color, frequency){
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
        this.frequency = frequency
    }
}

const player1 = new Node(100, 100, 30, 'blue',[1047])
const player2 = new Node(200, 100, 30, 'red',[1047, 1047])

var listOfNodes = []
listOfNodes.push(player1)
listOfNodes.push(player2)

function playNote(freq) {
        oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator()
        gain = audioCtx.createGain()
        oscillator.type = 'sine'
        oscillator.connect(gain)
        oscillator.frequency.value = freq
        gain.connect(audioCtx.destination)
        oscillator.start(0)
        gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.00001, audioCtx.currentTime + 1)
}

listOfNodes.forEach(node => {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < node.frequency.length; i++) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    playNote(node.frequency[i])
                }, 2000 * i);
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. For example you can set different start time for each `playNote`. Like this:

```
function playNote(freq, time) {
        oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator()
        gain = audioCtx.createGain()
        oscillator.type = 'sine'
        oscillator.connect(gain)
        oscillator.frequency.value = freq
        gain.connect(audioCtx.destination)
        oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime + time)
        gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.00001, audioCtx.currentTime + 1 + time)
}

for (i = 0; i < node.frequency.length; i++) {       
    playNote(node.frequency[i], i)          
}
```

Or use recursive function that is executed when one note ends. But for this you need to specify actual end time with `oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + sometime)`, not that ugly hack :) `gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.00001, audioCtx.currentTime + 1 + time)`

```
function playNote(freq) {
            oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator()
            gain = audioCtx.createGain()
            oscillator.type = 'sine'
            oscillator.connect(gain)
            oscillator.frequency.value = freq
            gain.connect(audioCtx.destination)
            oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime)
            oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + 1)
            oscillator.addEventListener('ended', () => {playNote(nextFrequency)}, { once: true });
}
```

But I think best way is to use modern javascript features: [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

class Node {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color, frequency){
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
        this.frequency = frequency
    }
}

const player1 = new Node(100, 100, 30, 'blue',[1047])
const player2 = new Node(200, 100, 30, 'red',[1047, 1047])

var listOfNodes = []
listOfNodes.push(player1)
listOfNodes.push(player2)

function playNote(freq) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator()
        gain = audioCtx.createGain()
        oscillator.type = 'sine'
        oscillator.connect(gain)
        oscillator.frequency.value = freq
        gain.connect(audioCtx.destination)
        oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime)
        oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + 1)
        oscillator.addEventListener('ended', resolve, { once: true });
  })
}

async function play() {
   for (const node of listOfNodes) {
       for (const frequency of node.frequency) {
          console.log(`note with frequenty ${frequency} started`)
          await playNote(frequency);
          console.log(`note with frequency ${frequency} ended`)
       }
   }
}
play();
```